# C max of sums - need to modify it to stop adding the sums

Tags: c, sum, max

This program needs to let users enter numbers and calculate the sum of factors for each entered number.

It needs to do this until the user enters a number that is odd and dividable by 5 (it does not calculate the sum of that last number). Then , it needs to list the number of sums calculated and the biggest sum.

The problem i'm having is that the program , instead of showing the biggest sum (max) it shows the sums of sums.

suma is the sum variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
int x ,i ,suma=0 ,nr=0 ,max=0;



while(1)
{
printf("Introduceti un intreg:\n");
scanf("%d",&x);

for(i=2;i<=x/2;i++)      //the for checks if i is a factor of x, then adds it to the

                         //sum of factors
{
if(x%i==0)
          suma = suma + i;
}

if (x%2!=0 && x%5==0)
          break;
          nr++;

if (suma>=max)
          max=suma;


}

printf("Numarul sumelor calculate este %d\n\n",nr);     //The number of sums calculated is
printf("suma este : %d",max);                           //The maximum sum is


}
```

Comment: `suma = 0` before `for`

Comment: So i guess if i didn't make the sum 0 after every time the max just added a new sum to the old one every time, right? Just so i understand it.

Comment: si :) tu entiendes ;)

Answer (score 1):

`suma` should be initialized before the `for` loop (so it is re-initialized for each sum), not at the stop of the program.

Comment: It still adds the sums when i put it before the for.

Answer (score 0):

es muy bien aqui

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
int x ,i ,suma,nr=0 ,max=0;



while(1)
{
printf("Introduceti un intreg:\n");
scanf("%d",&x);
suma=0;
for(i=2;i<=x/2;i++)      //the for checks if i is a factor of x, then adds it to the

                         //sum of factors
{
if(x%i==0)
       {   suma = suma + i;}
}

if (x%2!=0 && x%5==0)
       {   break;}
          nr++;

if (suma>=max)
         { max=suma;}


}

printf("Numarul sumelor calculate este %d\n\n",nr);     //The number of sums calculated is
printf("suma este : %d",max);                           //The maximum sum is


}
```